# dynamically create a number of dropdown lists based on user input

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a situation in which I have 1 dropdownlist containing numbers 1.....n as list items.
I have to code in such a way that if I select 3 from the list, 3 new dropdownlists are created each linked to a unique sql data source for their items.

I am really confused.

I would really appreciate a little guidance.

Thank You

Comment: This is a coding site; please supply code.

Comment: If I had known that I would not have asked the question in the first place. I am working on it Thank You for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok fist you need to have dropdownlist and a placeholder control on your .aspx web form like this:

> ```
>  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
>                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
>  </asp:DropDownList>
>
>  <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
> ```

then on your code behind DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged method you need to check the value of dropdown list and create your dropdown list in a loop like below:

> ```
>     protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         int count = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value);
>
>         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
>         {
>             DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
>             ddl.ID = "ddl" + i;
>             ddl.DataSource = //your data source here
>             ddl.DataBind();
>             PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(ddl);
>         }
>     }
> ```

let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: Thank You for the answer. I'm working it out